# Magento pagination not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination

I am trying to show custom collection with pagination that code is working when i moved that code to other theme then pagination not working properly according to records
please find the attached picture

[image]

Comment: Can you share code ?

Answer (score 0):

**Just follow the Steps according to this Blog:-**

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/18/magento-collection-paging/